# How to clear cache on building Gitlab?

Tags: python, django, docker, gitlab, docker-compose

Gitlab can't clean my cache on building.
How to fix this problem?

Executor: shell

```
Fetching changes...
warning: failed to remove config/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove config/settings/__pycache__/local.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove config/settings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove config/settings/__pycache__/common.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove config/settings/__pycache__/test.cpython-36.pyc
warning: failed to remove docs/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

Comment: You need to give more details on your setup. You tagged it with `docker` and `docker-compose` - is there anything running with Docker?

Comment: Project based on https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Comment: I am facing this exact issue, looking into it now...

Answer (score 3):

Luckily I was having the exact same issue as you (I think).

**A little background:**

> I was using gitlab ci to build using a remote runner (shell) that
>   would build a docker image and then run some tests.

**Cause:**

> I was mounting a local directory inside the container by passing the -v flag to `docker run` (there are other ways to do this with compose yml for example).
>
> Because the docker container runs as root the generated __pycache__ directories and files are owned by root on the local filesystem; This means that docker-runner does not have permission to delete them on the next build.

**The solution:**

> **Remove the mount and copy the files instead.**

Answer (score 2):

I workaround by not let python create `*.pyc` files

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE

Comment: while both answers are correct, I prefer this one for two reasons
1) it fits more elegantly with my deployment strategy
2) easier to -v PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 in a selenium container than to build a Dockerfile to COPY . /path when you are reusing a container for multiple projects